# ERROR: (gcloud.compute.instances.delete) Could not fetch resource: The resource not found

Tags: google-cloud-platform, gcloud

I would like to delete a secondary VM, spun up from the master VM already deleted, on Google Cloud Console. I tried several times from the console, anyway, by reloading the page, I can see it again loading.

From the console, it is **NOT** possible to:

- **Start**--> You can't start this VM instance because it's not stopped
- **Stop**--> You can't stop this VM instance because it's not running,
  suspended or being repaired.
- **Suspend**--> You can't suspend this VM instance because it's not
  running.
- **Reset**--> You can't reset this VM instance because it's not running.

I tried also to delete the browser cache, and from another browser, with the same issue persisting.

I also tried typing on the Cloud Shell Terminal:

```
gcloud --quiet compute instances delete projects/PROJECT-NAME/zones/europe-west4-b/instances/nf-f29c7405-169839-353a2991-c482-4fbb0-group0-0-0m4g
```

But still, I get the error:

```
ERROR: (gcloud.compute.instances.delete) Could not fetch resource:
 - The resource 'projects/PROJECT-NAME/zones/europe-west4-b/instances/nf-f29c7405-169839-353a2991-c482-4fbb0-group0-0-0m4g' was not found
```

Has anyone else experienced the same error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use the **--zone** parameter in your command.

```
gcloud compute instances delete instance_name --zone=europe-west4-b
```

See this [document](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/compute/instances/delete).